# No questions found. Site is down?

Tags: support, bug

Getting sporadic "no questions found" when I try to click any tag. This happened just now, the site's been fine for hours.

So it would appear that the site is down or misbehaving. Anyone else getting this or is it just me?

(Meta works fine, not just SO)

Comment: They might handle the filter the wrong way. Seems to be working now..

Comment: Yup, everything went blank for me, it then updates and shows "new" questions only

Comment: Happened for a minute. It's working fine for me now.

Comment: It lasted over 5 minutes for me, just started working now

Comment: Yep, coming back now. Some server hiccup.

Comment: I just had this happen on Movies.SE and I didn't even have a tag selected, I just clicked "Questions" in the sidebar. Refreshed and it was fine.

Comment: Cross-site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340457/security-stackexchange-com-it-was-not-possible-to-perform-this-tag-search-at-th

Comment: Don't close vote this just yet. They might want to investigate what happened and leave info below. Leave it open for a day at least.